# What do these Trigger errors mean

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger to update the Video table. I got this far and through google and anything else, but can't seem to find an answer for all these errors any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the trigger with the errors.

```
CREATE or REPLACE Trigger Available_Rule

 BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT (*) 
FROM Video, Transaction
WHERE Status = :new.Status;

IF :new.Date_Rented_Out  is not null AND IF :new.Date_Returned = NULL
 THEN 
   UPDATE Video
   set Status = Unavailable
   where Status = :new.Status;
 End IF;
 END;
/
show errors;

2/1  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
2/9  PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression  
4/16  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.STATUS'  
6/42  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> avg coun t current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string literal w ith character set specification> <a number> <a single-quoted S QL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal with c haracter set specification> <an alternatively-quoted  
10/19  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.STATUS'  
12/5  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting on e of the following: end not pragma final instantiable order o verriding static member constructor map
```

Comment: You only need an IF..IF x And y then..

Comment: Also use single quotes for unavailable `set Status = 'Unavailable'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
IF :new.Date_Rented_Out  is not null AND IF :new.Date_Returned = NULL
```

to this:

```
IF :new.Date_Rented_Out  is not null AND :new.Date_Returned is NULL
```

Lose    `= NULL`  and the extra IF